# LINQ Query incredibly slow - why?

Tags: c#, linq, performance, datacontext

I got a very simple LINQ query:

```
List<table> list = ( from t in ctx.table
                     where
                     t.test == someString
                     && t.date >= dateStartInt
                     && t.date <= dateEndInt
                     select t ).ToList<table>();
```

The table which gets queried has got about 30 million rows, but the columns `test` and `date` are indexed.
When it should return around 5000 rows it takes several minutes to complete.

I also checked the SQL command which LINQ generates.
If I run that command on the SQL Server it takes 2 seconds to complete.

What's the problem with LINQ here?
It's just a very simple query without any joins.

That's the query SQL Profiler shows:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [t0].[test]
FROM [dbo].[table] AS [t0]
WHERE ([t0].[test] IN (@p0)) AND ([t0].[date] >= @p1) 
AND ([t0].[date] <= @p2)',
N'@p0 nvarchar(12),@p1 int,@p2 int',@p0=N'123test',@p1=110801,@p2=110804
```

**EDIT:**

It's really weird. While testing I noticed that it's much faster now. The LINQ query now takes 3 seconds for around 20000 rows, which is quite ok.

What's even more confusing:
It's the same behaviour on our production server. An hour ago it was really slow, now it's fast again. As I was testing on the development server, I didn't change anything on the production server. The only thing I can think of being a problem is that both servers are virtualized and share the SAN with lots of other servers.

How can I find out if that's the problem?

Comment: SQL Server will cache queries, so you might not be performing a fair test.

Comment: Have you looked at the execution plan? Is the index fragmented?

Comment: Have a look with SQL Server Profiler to find out which query is *really* executed.

Comment: What I don't understand is, that we got another huge table with around 600 million rows and a query on that table takes just a second (with LINQ). Where does the difference come from? I never used SQL Server Profiler, but I'll try it now.

Comment: What's in the constructor for `table`? Anything going on in its property setters?

Comment: "table" is just the auto-generated LINQ-to-SQL-class.

Answer (score 2):

Before blaming LINQ first find out where the actual delay is taking place.

- Sending the query
- Execution of the query
- Receiving the results
- Transforming the results into local types
- Binding/showing the result in the UI
- And any other events tied to this process

Then start blaming LINQ ;)

Comment: I'd like to find out where the delay comes from but I don't know how :) How can I set a filter in SQL Server Profiler to just show actions on a specific table? There's happening too much on the server.

Comment: @Dave, Use the SQL Profiler to see when and what goes to and from the SQL Server. Strip down the client and use the Stopwatch class to time the steps.

Comment: @Dave, how do you expect me to help you with this level of information? Did you connect to the correct database (are you using a local copy?) are you monitoring for the correct events?

Comment: Alright, I found the query which LINQ sends. SQL Profiler is showing me the same duration as the Stopwatch in my App.

Comment: @Dave, could you add the query to your question?

Comment: The query has 730000 reads and a duration of 2500 milliseconds. Same query executed in SQL Management Studio has 400 reads and 200 milliseconds.

Comment: I added the query to my question

Comment: @Dave, another thing that might have happened during the previous test is that the indexes were rebuild. Depending on isolation levels you could also be running into locks from other users.

Comment: The indexes are rebuilt every night, not through the day. Also there's no one else working on the development server, just me.

Comment: @Dave, sorry I am out of ideas. Well I have many but I'd be shooting blindly ;)

Answer (score 2):

If I had to *guess*, I would say "parameter sniffing" is likely, i.e. it has built and cached a query plan based on *one* set of parameters, which is very suboptimal for your current parameter values. You can tackle this with `OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)` in regular TSQL, but there is no LINQ-to-SQL / EF way of expolsing this.

My plan would be:

1. use profiling to prove that the time is being lost in the *query* (as opposed to materialization etc)
2. once confirmed, consider using direct TSQL methods to invoke

For example, with LINQ-to-SQL, `ctx.ExecuteQuery<YourType>(tsql, arg0, ...)` can be used to throw raw TSQL at the server (with parameters as `{0}` etc, like `string.Format`). Personally, I'd lean towards "dapper" instead - very similar usage, but a faster materializer (but it doesn't support `EntityRef<>` etc for lazy-loading values - which is usually a bad thing anyway as it leads to N+1).

i.e. (with dapper)

```
List<table> list = ctx.Query<table>(@"
   select * from table
   where test == @someString
   and date >= @dateStartInt
   and date <= @dateEndInt
   OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)",
new {someString, dateStartInt, dateEndInt}).ToList();
```

or (LINQ-to-SQL):

```
List<table> list = ctx.ExecuteQuery<table>(@"
   select * from table
   where test == {0}
   and date >= {1}
   and date <= {2}
   OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)",
someString, dateStartInt, dateEndInt).ToList();
```

Comment: @Dave and you are testing it against the *same values*? Ok... what are the **full** DB types of `test` and `date`? for example, is `test` typed as `nvarchar(100)`, `char(20)`, etc?

Comment: Yes, it's exactly the same. I did a few runs and compared the duration with StopWatch. test is "nvarchar(12)" and date is "int".

Comment: @Dave are they regular columns? calculated values? persisted calculated values? ...?

Comment: just regular columns. Actually the second one takes about twice as long to finish as the normal linq query. I tested it with values, which return 4500 rows.

Comment: It's really weird.
While testing I noticed that it's much faster now.
The LINQ query now takes 3 seconds for around 20000 rows, which is quite ok.

What's even more confusing:
It's the same behaviour on our production server.
An hour ago it was really slow, now it's fast again.
As I was testing on the development server, I didn't change anything on the production server.

The only thing I can think of being a problem is that both servers are virtualized and share the SAN with lots of other servers.

How can I find out if that's the problem?